# JQUERY & CSS DOWN MENU - Unable to keep background of<li> highlighted when hovering over subitem(a div)

Tags: jquery, css, hoverintent

I created a mega dropdown menu with the hoverintent plugin which works like a charm, except the li background color wont stay black when i put my mouse into the subdiv.  I know its probably a silly fix, but I can't figure it out. Please help...

Site:http://www.nestudiosonline.com/test.php

html:

```
<ul id="menu">
        <li class="mega"><a class="dkeorg" href="#">DKE.ORG</a></li>
        <li class="megamenu" id="dave"><a class="links" href="#">ABOUT DKE</a> <div id="aboutdke">div content  </div></li>
        <li class="megamenu"><a class="links" href="#">ALUMNI</a></li>
        <li class="megamenu"><a class="links" href="#">UNDERGRADUATES</a></li>
        <li class="megamenu"><a class="links" href="#">EVENTS</a></li>
        <li class="megamenu"><a class="links" href="#">MULTIMEDIA</a></li>
        <li class="megamenu"><a class="links" href="#">SHOP DKE</a></li>
      </ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul#menu
{
    display:block;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

ul# menu li
{
    display:inline;
    position: relative;
    }

ul#menu div {
  display: none;
}

ul#menu li.mega div {
    position: absolute;
}

ul#menu li.hovering div {
  display: block;
}

#aboutdke
{
    display:block;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:left;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:10px;
    background-color:#000;
    margin:0;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    padding-left:10px;
    border:0px;
    width:910px;
    height:280px;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:99999;
    top:164px;
    left:140px;
}

a.links:link
{
    display:block;
    width:120px;
    height:22px;
    padding-top:8px;
    padding-left:3px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    outline:none;
    float:left;
}

a.links:visited 
    {
    display:block;
    width:120px;
    height:22px;
    padding-top:8px;
    padding-left:3px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    outline:none;
    float:left;
    } 

/* mouse over link */

a.links:hover
    {
    display:block;
    width:120px;
    height:22px;
    padding-top:8px;
    padding-left:3px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:underline;
    text-align:center;
    outline:none;
    background-color:#000;
    float:left;
    }   

/* selected link */

a.links:active
    {
    display:block;
    width:120px;
    height:22px;
    padding-top:8px;
    padding-left:3px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:underline;
    text-align:center;
    outline:none;
    background-color:#000;
    float:left;
    }
```

JQUERY:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
//<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {
//add hovering class to li's inside of the unordermened with the id menu     
      function addMega(){
        $(this).addClass("hovering");
        }
//remove hovering class to li's inside of the unordermened with the id menu  
      function removeMega(){
        $(this).removeClass("hovering");
        }
//configuariton for hoverintent plugin, hoveron time, mouse sensitivity, hoveroff time 
    var megaConfig = {
         interval: 300,
         sensitivity: 4,
         over: addMega,
         timeout: 200,
         out: removeMega
    };
//make list items with the class megamenu have the hoverinter plugin excuted on them 
    $("li.megamenu").hoverIntent(megaConfig)


    });


    //]]>
    </script>
```

Comment: Maybe he does, I sometimes do :P

Answer (score 0):

```
ul#menu li.hovering {
  background-color:#000;
}
```

So the list item itself will have a black background, all child elements - with transparent backgrounds themselves - will also have that parent's black background.

Comment: i tried that but its not working, is it because my links for those items in general have their own definitions as you can see above in my css. for example a.links hover:

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the case yeah, if you add some padding to li.hovering and change its background from black to.. hot pink, you'll soon find out :)

Comment: lol it changed the div inside the li to have a pink background put it did not effect the ABOUT DKE li item hmmm

Comment: Well, '#aboutdke' is actually on a div element, not the list item. That '#aboutdke' style declaration sets the background to black.. so naturally it won't be transparent and therefore show the pink from its parent through. Remove the background colour from the #aboutdke, and it'll be pink.

Comment: wait maybe i have you confused, sorry. I want the button About Dke to stay highlighted black when I am hovering #aboutdke. When I first put my mouse over ABOUT DKE it is black until i go into the div. I tried making #aboutdke background to transparent but that doesnt make ABOUT DKE black when im hovering in the div

Comment: Ok, with you, what colour should ABOUT DKE be, when you're hovering over the associated li.hovering element, but NOT hovering either ABOUT DKE or #aboutdke?

Comment: black, I want the link to be highlighted black still when i am hovering inside of aboutdke. It orginally starts off black when Im hovering but when I hover inside of about dke, it stops highlight in black because my mouse is no longer over it.

Comment: You give up on me sir? lol you were actually a help please come back

Comment: Heh, soz, at work, let me read :P  Ok, it actually sounds like it might be event related instead then. Imagine that you have attached a listener to the parent, so when you mouseover a child element it is actually mousing out of the parent because it found a new, more acute context (the #aboutdke div). I'm not sure how jquery handles this, but I do know that YUI implements a fix for this situation because IE buggers the process up. YUI's explanation can be found here: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/event/, Jquery seems to have it explained here: http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/